# How to find a formal documentation of Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Often, There are cases when I want to do something with Excel but I don't know how. I am looking for some detailed reference not a help tool..

for example, how to do the following ?

I have 2 columns. Lets' say column A and B.  I want to calc B the following way:\

```
B1 = A1 - A2
B2 = A2 - A3
Bn = An - A(n+1)
```

If An AND A(n+1) contain value.
How can I do that ?
How can I learn more about similar things in Excel ?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel does the adjustment of the cell references automatically when the formula is copied.

So, all you need is to start in cell B1 with

```
=A1-A2
```

and copy that cell down as far as you have values in column A. You can click and drag the fill handle, i.e. the dot at the lower right hand of the active cell to copy a formula down.

Or you can copy the cell, then select all the target cells and use your favourite paste command.